# images do not appear on my java applet

Tags: java, eclipse, image, applet

Hey I'm trying to create a video game and I'm testing to see if I can make a sprite or image appear on the applet I've asked for help before from my peers and professor, but they don't seem to help. I don't know if I have the image in the wrong location or if my code is bugged, but I would appreciate if someone took a look at it Thanks! Oh! by the way I'm programming in Java and I'm using Eclipse JUNO.

```
enter code here

package meh;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


public class Draw  extends JApplet{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Draw test = new Draw();


    }
    private Image exImage;
    private boolean imagesLoaded;

    public void run()
    {

        imagesLoaded = false;

        try
        {
            loadImages();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(10000);

            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){}
        }
        finally{}


    }
    public void loadImages()
    {
        exImage = loadImage("C:/Users/Temp/workspace/From Scratch/bin/Ma_rn_0");
        imagesLoaded = true;
        repaint();
    }
    private Image loadImage(String fileName)
    {
        return new ImageIcon(fileName).getImage();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        if(g instanceof Graphics2D)
        {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        }
        if(imagesLoaded)
        {
            drawImage(g, exImage,0,0, null);
        }
        else
        {
            g.drawString("Loading...", 5, 12);
        }
    }

    public void drawImage(Graphics g, Image image, int x, int y, String caption)
    {
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
        g.drawString(caption, x+5, y + 12 +image.getHeight(null));
    }

}
```

Comment: *"I've asked for help before from my peers and professor, but they don't seem to help."*  It seems you should be looking for a better educational institution than tossing that rubbish code at us to fix.  As a general tip, don't code applets until you are confident with both GUI programming and debugging.  The code above, combined with your comments, suggests that neither is the case.

Comment: Sorry, but you don't tell me what to do =]

Answer (score 1):

Unless they are signed, applets can only load images from the same location from where they originated. Here you are attempting to load an image from the local disk. All initialisation for applet resources should be done from the `init` method. Images can be loaded as resources from the same JAR file from which they are deployed. You could do

```
Image exImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/MyImage.jpg"))
```

Answer (score 0):

1 `public static void main(String[] args)`

Applets are not supposed to have `main()`, it uses `init`, `start`, `stop` and `destroy`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html

2 Try to learn about `EDT` concept

3 Don't override `paint` method

4 Use `ImageIO` to load images